# How to install sp (R package) from existing .gz file?

Tags: r, installation

I typed codes in R to download sp package, it says -- Package ‘sp’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1).

I downloaded sp manually from http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/src/contrib/sp_1.0-9.tar.gz. Questions is: how to unpack the tar.gz file? I work with RGui in windows 7.

Thanks!!

Comment: Hm, I just downloaded and installed the binary via `install.packages("sp")`. I'm also using R 3.0.1 on Windows, and I even got it from the UCLA mirror just to be sure. Try again and see if it works.

Comment: `install.packages("sp")` worked for me on `RHEL 7.7`

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you work with RStudio, hit 'Tools' --> 'Install packages' and you're able to select the .tar.gz file from your local system.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the file locally, then you can use the following:

```
R> install.packages(sp_package_path, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

where `sp_package_path` is the path to the source package (.tar.gz file).

Comment: Does this work on a Windows system?

Comment: Rtools are required on Windows, since the package includes some C-Code (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)

Answer (score 1):

What was the code that you entered? What was the error message that you received?

Try:

```
install.packages("sp")
```

If that fails, try:

```
install.packages("sp", dependencies=TRUE)
```

If that fails, please update your question with the exact error message.